# Change Variable Value with Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I want a variable (chanceoflive) to be **stored with localStorage**. Then, I have radio buttons. I want it so that depending on which radio button is selected, the variable chanceoflive will be changed. This is what I have:

```js
var chanceoflive = 0;
var user;
function choose(choice){
    user = choice;
}

function changechanceoflive(){
    if (user == brick) {
        chanceoflive += 1;
    }
    else if (user == wood) {
        chanceoflive +=3
    }
    else if (user == stone) {
        chanceoflive +=2
    }
    localStorage.setItem("chanceoflive", chanceoflive);
}

function test(click){
    alert(chanceoflive);
}
```

```html
<div id="radiobuttons" class="container" name="buttons" align=center>

  <h2>I Want my Building to be Made of:</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="brick-option" name="material" value="1" onClick="choose('Bricks')">
      <label for="brick-option">Bricks</label>

      <div class="check"></div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="wood-option" name="material" value="3" onClick="choose('Wood')">
      <label for="wood-option">Wood</label>

      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="stone-option" name="material" value="2" onClick="choose('Stone')">
      <label for="stone-option">Stone</label>

      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<form action="chooseheight.html">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button" onClick="test();changechanceoflive()" align=center>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Although, it always just alerts 0. Is it a problem with localStorage or something else?

Comment: Where do you set `brick`, `wood`, and `stone`? Did you mean for those to be literal strings? Then you need to quote them.

Comment: Check your Javascript console for error messages.

Comment: `if (user == brick) {` is not equal to `onClick="choose('Bricks')`. Change `brick` to `'brick'` (add quotes) in the if-clause, and change `'Bricks'` also to `'brick'` (loose capital 'B' and 's') in the onclick. Same for `stone` and `wood`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your code:

```
<ul>
<li>
  <input type="radio" id="brick-option" name="material" value="1" onClick="choose('bricks')">
  <label for="brick-option">Bricks</label>

  <div class="check"></div>
</li>

<li>
  <input type="radio" id="wood-option" name="material" value="3" onClick="choose('wood')">
  <label for="wood-option">Wood</label>

  <div class="check">
    <div class="inside"></div>
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <input type="radio" id="stone-option" name="material" value="2" onClick="choose('stone')">
  <label for="stone-option">Stone</label>

  <div class="check">
    <div class="inside"></div>
  </div>
</li>
```

JS

```
var chanceoflive = 0;
var user;
function choose(choice){
    user = choice;
}

function changechanceoflive(){
    if (user == 'bricks') {
        chanceoflive += 1;
    }
    else if (user == 'wood') {
        chanceoflive +=3
    }
    else if (user == 'stone') {
        chanceoflive += 2
    }
    localStorage.setItem("chanceoflive", chanceoflive);
}

function test(click){
    alert(chanceoflive);
    alert(localStorage.chanceoflive);
}
```

But with your code, if the user reload the page and then didn't select any radio, the localStorage variable will be reset to 0 because your have

> var chanceoflive = 0;

If you want to keep the last saved value, you must replace that line by:

> var chanceoflive = localStorage.chanceoflive;

Comment: Do I have to set the localstorage variable at the end when the user presses the button and goes to the next page?

Comment: @NathanChan keeping the line `localStorage.setItem("chanceoflive", chanceoflive)` at the end of the **changechanceoflive** is just fine, you can see that it is setted properly with the alert in the **test** function.

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your part about LocalStorage, just set/get your variables like a regular Javascript object. More info: [mrkdown.io/t32iomd](http://mrkdown.io/t32iomd)